# Does Java Web Start give a default program folder?

Tags: java, directory, java-web-start

For Java Web Start is there a default place to store and access data related to my program? Or do I need to create a folder? For Java Web Start (assuming I don't get a program folder) is it standard to just create on in Program Files for window, Applications for mac, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a subdirectory in the users home directory. E.g. System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + ".myapp/"

But for that the user has to add extra permissions for the a web start application.

To persist you can use a properties file or XmlEncoder which are included in the JDK. Or use external libraries like [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/), [Xvantage](http://github.com/karussell/xvantage) or [the simple framework](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) where it is simple as

```
xstream.save(anyObject)
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the [Preferences API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) for storing user settings there are a few services that can be found in [the `javax.jnlp` package](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/index.html).

For your concrete requirement the [`PersistenceService`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/PersistenceService.html) would be particularly useful.

Alternatively you can simply provide all data that your application requires as part of your `.jar` files, reference them in your `.jnlp` file and customize how and when they are downloaded by using the [`DownloadService`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/DownloadService.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific default place to store and access data related to your program with webstart. However Java does have the [Preferences API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) to provide a platform independant way of storing configuration without worrying about the specific storage location/format.

Comment: Ok thanks, so if I wanted to store say an sqlite db, I'd basically just try to conform to the practices of the system for creating the program folder?

Comment: If you wanted to use a sqlite db I would say that best practice would be to store it under the user directory.